# How to reorder object array by using order array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to reorder some objects in an array.

Assume this is my data array:

```
const data = [
  { id: 'ETHUVMY0m', name: 'item 1', value: 'value 1' },
  { id: 'McfTB40vO', name: 'item 2', value: 'value 2' }
]
```

And there is another array, which represents the new order:

```
const order = [ 'McfTB40vO', 'ETHUVMY0m' ]
```

As you can see, the second item gets on the first place.

So the result should be:

```
[
  { id: 'McfTB40vO', name: 'item 2', value: 'value 2' },
  { id: 'ETHUVMY0m', name: 'item 1', value: 'value 1' }
]
```

I thought of using an forEach loop:

```
data.forEach(d => {
  order.indexOf(d.id) // get new index
  // but how to reorder the array?
})
```

Comment: you would build your own custom `sort` and pass the custom function to sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `data` to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of objects by `id`. Then use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `order` array, and get the relevant item from the Map:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 'ETHUVMY0m', name: 'item 1', value: 'value 1' },
  { id: 'McfTB40vO', name: 'item 2', value: 'value 2' }
]

const order = [ 'McfTB40vO', 'ETHUVMY0m' ]

const dataMap = new Map(data.map(o => [o.id, o]))
const result = order.map(id => dataMap.get(id))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it immutably, use map and find, not forEach:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 'ETHUVMY0m', name: 'item 1', value: 'value 1' },
  { id: 'McfTB40vO', name: 'item 2', value: 'value 2' }
];

const order = [ 'McfTB40vO', 'ETHUVMY0m' ];

const result = order.map(id => data.find(x => x.id === id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) `order` into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) before using `Array.prototype.map()`, you can perform this in O(n) using [`Map.prototype.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) instead of `Array.prototype.find()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I don't understand what you suggest. Could you give an example?

Comment: @user3142695, look at Ori Drori's answer for a solution using `Map.get()`, which is more efficient than using `find()`

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` over `order`:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 'ETHUVMY0m',
    name: 'item 1',
    value: 'value 1'
  },
  {
    id: 'McfTB40vO',
    name: 'item 2',
    value: 'value 2'
  }
]

const order = ['McfTB40vO', 'ETHUVMY0m']

const output = order.map(d => data.find(({
  id
}) => d == id));

console.log(output);
```